# How to load xml resource file using wild card in Spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring, resources, classpath, wildcard

I want to load xml files which contains some error definitions of several modules in a Spring Maven project. I want to load and then pass the file to a JAXB unmasheller.

This is what I have done so far

```
String path = "classpath*:/**/definitions/error-definition.xml";
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(path);
unmarshaller.unmarshall(resource);
```

My resource files are located as follows

`src/main/resource/module1/definitions/error-definition.xml`

```
src/main/resource/module2/definitions/error-definition.xml
```

This gives me the following error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath*:/**/definitions/error-definition.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

but when I change the path as follows

```
 String path = "/module1/definitions/error-definition.xml";
```

It works

Following are the other wild card which I tried with no luck

```
String paths = "classpath:/**/definitions/error-definition.xml";
String paths = "classpath*:error-definition.xml";
String paths = "classpath*:*.xml";
```

What I want to do is to use wild card to get the xml files from any folder under `src/main/resource`

I referred several previous SO answers but still couldn't figure out what Im doing wrong.

Comment: A `ClassPathResource` is, as the name implies, a single resource. Wildcards only work with a `ResourcePatternResolver` when you pass it into the `getResources` method, this will give you an array of `Resource`s.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried applicationContext.getResources() and it works and I can get the file names. Thanks . Is it the only way of doing this? because we are trying to avoid injecting applicationContext

Comment: You don't need the `ApplicationContext` you can also inject the `ResourceLoader` and use the `ResourcePatternUtils` to load the desired resources. You will probably still get the `ApplicationContext` but it is more hidden for you (and clearer that you want to load resources).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To load resource inject the `ResourceLoader` into your class. You can do this by either implementing `ResourceLoaderAware` or simply annotate a field of type `ResourceLoader` with `@Autowired`.

```
public class YourClass {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader rl;

}
```

Now that you have the `ResourceLoader` you can use the `ResourcePatternUtils` to actually load the resources.

```
public Resource[] loadResources() {
    return ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(rl).getResources("classpath:/directory/**/*-context.xml);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried ResourcePatternResolver and it seems working but this returns the file path as "E:\path\path\META-INF\module1\definitions\file.xml" but I want to return the path as  \META-INF\module1\definitions\file.xml (without the physical location) . Do I need to do any string manipulation to get it or is there any other way?

Comment: And why is that a problem? That is the actual location and not \META-INF as that would be loaded from the root of the filesystem.

Comment: yes. you are correct that's not a problem. that comment was due to minor misunderstanding in my project. no worries. :) Thanks for the support and I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Keep in mind 'getResources' throws an IOException if it can't find any matching files, as opposed to returning an empty List.