# IntelliJ web application resources missing from classpath

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, classpath

I'm using IntelliJ to build a standard java web application on top of Tomcat and Spring.  I'm fairly new to IntellJ and feel like I'm missing something setup wise because I cannot seem to resolve resource files from the classpath.

Relevant Info -
IJ 2017.1.4
Tomcat 8.5.15
Java 8
Spring platform-bom:2.0.8.RELEASE

I should also mention I'm using a java only configuration, taking advantage of the Spring's annotations and the servlet 3.0+ spec.

Since I'm pretty sure this is an issue with my IJ configuration, here's a series of screenshots outlining my setup & the error.  Appreciate any help on this one, it's had me stumped for a bit.

Modules

[image: module structure]

Facets
[image: facets]

Artifacts
[image: artifact structure]

Project src

[image: project src structure]

Exploded War ouptut
[image: exploded war output]

Code where I'm attempting to load in a file on the classpath
[image: code]

Error
[image]

Comment: Resources are not in the root of your classpath, but in a subdirectory/package. You are trying to load them like they are exactly in the root.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I'm confused by it.  My understanding is that the contents of the src folder: src/main/resources - when marked as a resource in IJ - will get put into the WEB-INF/ directory.


So i have in my exploded war WEB-INF/classes, and WEB-INF/db/scripts/h2.  Which seems correct.

classpath*:test_DDL.sql should resolve anything on the classpath with the wildcard, but i have also tried db/scripts/h2/test_DDL.sql and /db/scripts/h2/test_DDL.sql with the same result.


Is the root of the classpath not where I think it is?

Comment: How would the app know that the resource is under `db.scripts.h2` package? Where do you specify this path in the code?

Comment: second to last image in the post - the classpath*: wildcard should be picking up any resource on the classpath, though as mentioned above i have also tried to use fully qualified paths to no avail

Comment: Wildcards will not work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100813/how-to-load-xml-resource-file-using-wild-card-in-spring-3-1#comment35310869_23100813.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it looks like ClassPathResource does not accept wildcards since it expects a single resource.  When I get home I will try classpath:/db/scripts/h2/test_DDL.sql or use wildcards with ResourcePatternUtils.